# split pandas frame into multiple frames based on timedelta

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to figure out how to split a pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes based on time delta of a specified column. So, given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'timestamp': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })

df = df.drop(df.index[[2]])
```

This results in:

```
       timestamp       Val
0 2015-02-24 00:00:00  0.010965
1 2015-02-24 00:01:00 -1.677391
3 2015-02-24 00:03:00 -1.079073
4 2015-02-24 00:04:00  1.534352
```

Now, the frequency I want too split by is:

```
freq = pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(df.timestamp).min())
# Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')
```

Now I am stuck in this final step where I want to split this frame into multiple subframes wherever this delta is more than this minimum.

Expected output:

```
[
       timestamp       Val
0 2015-02-24 00:00:00  0.010965
1 2015-02-24 00:01:00 -1.677391

       timestamp       Val
0 2015-02-24 00:03:00 -1.079073
1 2015-02-24 00:04:00  1.534352
]
```

Comment: Could you share what your expected output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff` to calculate the difference between adjacent timestamps and compare it with `freq`, then `split` by positions using `numpy.split`:

```
import numpy as np
np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(df.timestamp.diff() > freq))

[            timestamp       Val
0 2015-02-24 00:00:00  0.123225
1 2015-02-24 00:01:00 -1.786254,             timestamp       Val
3 2015-02-24 00:03:00  0.291738
4 2015-02-24 00:04:00 -0.548131]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Label the groups to split the DataFrame by.  I check where the difference in time is greater than `freq`, and then take a cumulative sum:

```
>>> grouper = df['timestamp'].diff().gt(freq).cumsum()
>>> grouper
0    0
1    0
3    1
4    1
Name: timestamp, dtype: int64
```

2. Groupby these labels and collect the separated DataFrames:

```
>>> [x for _, x in df.groupby(grouper)]
[            timestamp       Val
 0 2015-02-24 00:00:00  0.233784
 1 2015-02-24 00:01:00  0.804347,
             timestamp       Val
 3 2015-02-24 00:03:00 -0.343961
 4 2015-02-24 00:04:00 -0.891574]
```

In one line:

```
dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['timestamp'].diff().gt(freq).cumsum())]
```